# why does sort(key=lambda x: x[0]) sort by the first value in each element inside a list?

Tags: python

```
def can_attend_all_appointments(intervals):

    intervals.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

    return False

def main():
    print("Can attend all appointments: " + str(can_attend_all_appointments([[1, 4], [2, 5], [7, 9]])))
    print("Can attend all appointments: " + str(can_attend_all_appointments([[6, 7], [2, 4], [8, 12]])))
    print("Can attend all appointments: " + str(can_attend_all_appointments([[4, 5], [2, 3], [3, 6]])))


main()
```

why in this solution does intervals.sort(key=lambda x: x[0]) sort by the starting value in each element in a list? Doesn't x[0] just means the first element in the list

Comment: it means the first element of each sublist here, the lambda function is applied to each element

Comment: Any feedback on the answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a list, you sort it by comparing elements. Normally, this is straight forward. If you had a list

```
[1, 2, 8, 7, 3, 4]
```

It makes sense to just compare values by the natural ordering of the numbers. But how do I compare a list of lists by only comparing their first element? Or, what if I have a list of strings and I want to sort by the number of characters in each string so that the strings with the least number of characters come first. In this case, we want to provide a key.

The key tells python what aspect of an element is used to compare two values. So if we provide `len` as the key, we compare their lengths. If we provide `x[0]`, we compare their first element. Thus the key `x[0]` tell's python to compare each list with one another using their first element.

In your example with the key `x[0]`, Python would compare the two values

```
[1, 4], [2, 5]
```

by their first element, so`[1, 4] < [2, 5]` because `1 < 2`.